# how to use group by on spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark Dataset (Spark 1.6.1 Version).
Below is my code

```
object App { 

val conf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster("local")
.setAppName("SparkETL")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
import sqlContext.implicits._

}

override def readDataTable(tableName:String):DataFrame={
val dataFrame= App.sqlContext.read.jdbc(JDBC_URL, tableName, JDBC_PROP);
return dataFrame;
}


case class Student(stud_id , sname , saddress)
case class Student(classid, stud_id, name)


var tbl_student = JobSqlDAO.readDataTable("tbl_student").filter("stud_id = '" + studId + "'").as[Student].as("tbl_student")

var tbl_class_student = JobSqlDAO.readDataTable("tbl_class_student").as[StudentClass].as("tbl_class_student")


 var result = tbl_class_student.joinWith(tbl_student, $"tbl_student.stud_id" === $"tbl_class_student.stud_id").as("ff")
```

now i wanted to perform group by clause on multiple columns ?
 How to do it?
  `result.groupBy(_._1._1.created_at)` this way can i do it?
if yes , then i cannot see result as a group by also how to do it on multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your requirements, your best option here is to use `reduceByKey` function in [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) class.

The signature of the function is  `def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]` and it simply mean you use a series of key/value pairs.

Let me explain the workflow:

1. You retrieve the set you mant to work with (in your code: `result`)
2. With the RDD `map` function you split the result set in a tuple containing two subtuples containing the fields composing the key and the fields you want to aggregate (example: `result.map(row => ((row.key1, row.key2), (row.value1, row.value2))`)
3. Now you have a RDD[(K,V)] where type K is the type of the key fields tuple and V is the type of value fields tuple
4. You can directly use `reduceByKey` by passing a function of type `(V,V) => V` which aggregate values (example: `(agg: (Int, Int), val: (Int, Int)) => (agg._1 + val._1, agg._2 + val._2)`)

Please note:

- You have to return the same value type from the aggregation function
- You have to import `org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` to automatically use the PairRDDFunctions utility functions
- The same reasoning goes for `groupBy`, you have to map from the starting RDD to a pair `RDD[K,V]`, but you don't have an aggregate function because you are simply storing values in a seq for further computation
- If you need a starting value for the aggregation (example: 0 for counting) use instead `foldByKey` function